# CppCMS Hello World app with MS vc 2013 Express

Tags: c++, makefile, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, cppcms

I'd like to build a "Hello World" app with CppCMS, but now I have to face some problems.
I tried with MS solution and now I know it's not supported. But at the same time I also noticed there are some includes which doesn't exist e.g.: cppcms/config.h is refereed however there isn't there.

How I can use CppCMS with my Studio 2013? Should I use makefile? Can I use MS makefile project? I would be happy if you share an example makefile and command how I should run it.

**EDIT, second part: add additional (bonus) question :-)**

Why cannot I find shared host which supports C++ ?
I wanted to make my C++ site public but as I noticed there is no support to this ... :-(
If you had an app created by you where could you use? Should I do a server myself (I need static IP for this)?

New:

Thanks the comments, now I've lots of good idea for the first part but I still cannot compile the lib itself. I installed everything and cmake too. The configuration failed with lots of red lines :-)

I'm using CMAKE GUI.
My very first problem is this:

```
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules CPack.cmake:282      (message):
    CPack.cmake has already been included!!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
   booster/CMakeLists.txt:14 (include)
```

I just never heard about similar stuffs and I guess there is problem on my side. I just download the lib with its dependencies.

I'm using MS VC 2013.

Thanks, Tamás

Comment: Hmmm... if you want to programming web in C++ under Win I can suggest you this: http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/projects/wt/wiki/Installing_Wt_on_MS_Windows
They did an installer for Win and MS VC 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own home server may be suitable until enough traffic comes. Use a dynamic DNS service to overcome IP changes.

Comment: This morning I also had a similar idea. What do you think if I want to prove service to 20-30 people at the same time, how much is the enough internet speed? I guess 1-3 Mbps upload is not enough.
(of course I know it depends on my service, but I'm not sure that complexity and I need to plan a bit..)

Comment: Start with your own server. It will enable fast development/deployment. If bandwidth requirements are not high, 30 simultaneous connections are OK. Also note that I'm not aware of any available CPPCMS hosting, so if you go that way a dedicated server will be required.